# How to control the size of the output PDF?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to convert a list of images (`png`) to a single PDF using `imagemagick`.

I've tried using `convert *.png -size 375 output.pdf`, however the resulting PDF remains much wider than the source images.

How can I get the PDF to match the size of the images - which all have a width of 375px?

**Update:**

Another way to say this is:

How do I create a PDF with it's page size equal to the height of it's corresponding image?

**Update:**

To illustrate the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

I created 3 new PNG files with sizes more similar to yours using:

```
convert -size 375x10000 gradient:red-cyan     1.png
convert -size 375x10000 gradient:blue-magenta 2.png
convert -size 375x10000 gradient:silver-gold  3.png
```

and put them together in a 3-page PDF like this:

```
convert [123].png a.pdf
```

And I get this, which looks correct to me. I can only think you need to update your ImageMagick version, and/or your ghostscript version.

[image][[image]][[image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtsLU.png)

**Original Answer**

Not sure what the problem is, here is what I did and it seems to work fine:

```
# Synthesise 4 pages, each 375px wide
convert -size 375x800 xc:red    1.png
convert -size 375x800 xc:yellow 2.png
convert -size 375x800 xc:lime   3.png
convert -size 375x800 xc:blue   4.png

# Now assemble into a PDF
convert [1234].png output.pdf

# Check what we produced
identify -verbose output.pdf | more

Image: output.pdf
  Format: PDF (Portable Document Format)
  Mime type: application/pdf
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 375x800+0+0
  Resolution: 72x72
  Print size: 5.20833x11.1111
  Units: Undefined
  Type: PaletteAlpha
  Base type: TrueColorAlpha
  ...
  ...
```

Comment: The problem is that each image is 375px wide but ranges between 10,000px and 15,000px high, and the PDF pages constrain it's contents to fit the hight of a letter sized page.  I am trying to let the PDF page size match the width and height of it's corresponding image.  I am trying your solution now.

Comment: Using -size 375x800, the generated PDF has page sizes that exactly match the solid color images.  Is there a way to get this to work with variable heights?

Comment: Aha! Your question didn't mention that the images are 10,000 pixels tall!!! How do you expect it to lay out the images please? If an image is 375x10,000 it is always going to look tall and thin, isn't it?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion.  I am hoping to match the PDF page size to it's corresponding image size.  For example, page 1 would have a size of 375x10835 and page 2 would have a size of 375x11293, etc.  Tall and thin is totally expected.  The idea is that all screenshots needs to be concatenated into a PDF where each "page" of the PDF corresponds to a state.

Comment: I really appreciate your help on this.  If it is not possible to do with imagemagick, that's okay.  But I am wondering if there is a way to have the size of the PDF page match the image size.  For example, currently, the image is constrained to the height of the page.  This results in lots of whitespace in each PDF page.  Instead, can we "stretch" the image to be 100% width of the PDF page, with whatever height it has?

Comment: Maybe you want something like this... `convert [123].png -resize 4000x! result.pdf` which will make the images all 4000 pixels wide and leave the height unchanged.

Comment: If I use `covert 1.png -page 375x10000 result.pdf`, I get a custom page size, however the image is not found within this custom page.  Is there a way to force the image to appear within this custom page size?